How to call Azure ML via ADF every 10 minutes?
I am new to using Azure and I’m calling an Azure ML pipeline from a Data Factory pipeline and I used input data in the Azure ML pipeline.  Below you can see the pipeline. In this pipeline, I use import data to retrieve a CSV file from Blob Storage and with execute python script, I process the data coming from dataset1. The resulting output is written back to Blob Storage as a different CSV file using export data. I then include this pipeline in a Data Factory pipeline as a Machine Learning execute pipeline. The CSV file I use as input is updated in Data Factory every time the pipeline runs and new data is added. However, the Machine Learning pipeline is using the data from when it was first created, without taking the updated version of the CSV file I provided as input and it runs the pipeline again with the old data. What can I use instead of input data? How can I send the data to the Azure ML pipeline?


Edit: First, I am creating a datastore in Azure ML and linking it to an Azure Blob Storage container. While using "Import Data," I select the data storage I created and the CSV file I want to read within the relevant container.
During the "Copy Data" process, I select Blob Storage as the sink for the data I retrieve from the database, choosing the same CSV file used in "Import Data" under the container. When I go to Blob Storage and download the CSV file, I see that it adds a new day's data to the file with each "Copy Data" operation. However, on the Azure ML side, the input file being read works with the date when the pipeline was first created, and it seems that the datastore is not updating the input file.
Is it possible that the datastore is not updating the input file? How can I ensure that Azure ML retrieves new data from the CSV or database each time the pipeline runs?

Do you know the CSV file name prior to the machine learning activity? And are you giving the same file name in the copy activity sink dataset?

Data coming from Import data component will be cached for faster execution.
So, in Import data component you enable Regenerate output option under Output settings.

Now you can able to get the updated records.

My account is a student account, and I am the only user. When I use "Regenerate output for export data," it gives the error: "Failed to submit job due to Exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (User starting the run is not an owner or assigned user to the Compute Instance). The user starting the run is not an owner or assigned user to the Compute Instance."

You check mark Regenerate output for import data component. also make sure you have the permissions for running the pipeline.
